# All checks have failed due to Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue

Tags: javascript, github, gruntjs, jquery-select2

I am not a regular developer.
All I wanted was to add a language translation to [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2); translated the default `src/js/select2/i18n/en.js` file contents, created new file with changing labels from English to non-english.
Upon submitting the pull request, I see the All checks have failed and below the CI/Linting result:

```
Run grunt compile lint
Running "requirejs:dist" (requirejs) task
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
'/home/runner/work/select2/select2/src/js/select2/i18n/en.js'
In module tree:
select2/core
select2/options
select2/defaults
Warning: RequireJS failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
##[error]Process completed with exit code 6.
```

Same is the results with CI/Tests and CI/Minification.
What needs to be done to get the translation file successfully merged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The build of your first [pull request](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5859) failed as your commit had deleted the **en.js** file as mentioned in this PR [comment](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5859#issuecomment-632425697). That is the error log that you have mentioned in this question of yours.

Your second [pull request](https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/5870) is failing due to the below mentioned reasons in the build log

```
Running "jshint:code" (jshint) task

   src/js/select2/i18n/te.js
     13 |                var message = overChars + ' అక్షరం తొలిగించండి';
                             ^ 'message' is already defined.
     16 |            return message;
                            ^ 'message' used out of scope.
     31 |                var message = 'మీరు ' + args.maximum + ' అంశాల్ని మాత్రమే ఎంచుకోగలరు';
                                                                                              ^ Line is too long.
     33 |                var message = 'మీరు ' + args.maximum + ' అంశాన్ని మాత్రమే ఎంచుకోగలరు';
                                                                                              ^ Line is too long.
     33 |                var message = 'మీరు ' + args.maximum + ' అంశాన్ని మాత్రమే ఎంచుకోగలరు';
                             ^ 'message' is already defined.
     36 |            return message;
                            ^ 'message' used out of scope.

>> 6 errors in 103 files
```

Wherever you see `'message' is already defined` and `'message' used out of scope`, it is due to incorrectly defining the `message` variable multiple times and using the variable outside its scope. The error `Line is too long` is due to the particular line exceeding the max limit per line set as part of the linting config.

Change your `inputTooLong` function to

```
   inputTooLong: function (args) {
        var overChars = args.input.length - args.maximum;
        var message = overChars;

        if (overChars != 1) {
            message += ' అక్షరాలు తొలిగించండి';
        } else {
            message += ' అక్షరం తొలిగించండి';
        }

        return message;
    }
```

And change your `maximumSelected` function to

```
   maximumSelected: function (args) {
        var message = 'మీరు ' + args.maximum;

        if (args.maximum != 1) {
            message += ' అంశాల్ని మాత్రమే ఎంచుకోగలరు';
        } else {
            message += ' అంశాన్ని మాత్రమే ఎంచుకోగలరు';
        }

        return message;
    }
```

You also have given more indentation than what's expected. Compare the file [en.js](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/src/js/select2/i18n/en.js) in the repo with your changes and get rid of the extra indentation too accordingly.

**Note:** I would advise you to **run the linting build on your local machine** using the command `grunt compile lint` as specified in their GitHub action [config](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml#L18), so that you can **get to know of any errors before pushing your change** to the GitHub repository.